# ¿Cómo puedo identificar el Id de un Vehiculo en Android Studio por medio de Firebase

Tags: android, update, crud, android-recyclerview, arrayadapter

Buen día, miren asi tengo organizada mi base de datos en Firebase:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno en este caso el nodo de Vehiculo están dentro del usuario registrado y aqui se muestra:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok , el código que se muestra es un fragment compuesto por un RecyclerView donde están los datos extraidos de la base de datos:

```
public class Perfil extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
SearchView idBuscador;
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference RecycleBD;
private RecyclerView recycler;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;
private ArrayList<Vehiculos> list;
private ArrayList<Vehiculo> listaCompleta;

VehiculosAdapter adapter;
AdaptadorVehiculo adapter2;
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
public Perfil() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public static Perfil newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Perfil fragment = new Perfil();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
   }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    /*return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);*/
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil,container,false);
    recycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaVehiculos);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);


    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String id2=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    RecycleBD= 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(id2).child("Vehiculo");
    idBuscador=(SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    idBuscador.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    if (RecycleBD != null) {
        RecycleBD.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    list=new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String anio=ds.child("AnioFabricacion").getValue(String.class);
                        String chasis=ds.child("Chasis").getValue(String.class);
                        String motor=ds.child("Motor").getValue(String.class);
                        String tonelaje=ds.child("Tonelaje").getValue(String.class);
                        String placa=ds.child("NumeroPlaca").getValue(String.class);
                        String marca=ds.child("ModeloVehiculo").getValue(String.class);
                        String modelo=ds.child("Modelo").getValue(String.class);
                        list.add(new 
         Vehiculos(modelo,placa,marca,anio,chasis,motor,tonelaje));
                    }
                    adapter= new VehiculosAdapter(list);
                    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {             
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
     @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
      }
     @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        adapter.filtrado(s);
        return false;
      }
     }
```

Asi se muestra el fragment , se hace click en cada Cardview y se muestra una ventana emergente donde se muestran todos los datos a actualizar o eliminar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, como se sabe , el recyclerview tiene un modelo y un adapter , el modelo se muestra el código:

```
public class Vehiculos {
    private String modelo;
    private String marca;
    private String placa;
    private String anio;
    private String chasis;
    private String motor;
    private String tonelaje;
public Vehiculos() {
 }
public Vehiculos(String modelo, String placa, String marca,String anio,String chasis,String 
motor,String tonelaje) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.placa = placa;
    this.anio=anio;
    this.chasis=chasis;
    this.motor=motor;
    this.tonelaje=tonelaje;
 }

 public String getModelo() {
    return modelo;
 }

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}


public String getPlaca() {
    return placa;
}

public String getAnio() {
    return anio;
}

public String getChasis() {
    return chasis;
}

public String getMotor() {
    return motor;
}

public String getTonelaje() {
    return tonelaje;
}
public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}
public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}
public void setPlaca(String placa) {
    this.placa = placa;
}

public void setAnio(String anio) {
    this.anio = anio;
}

public void setChasis(String chasis) {
    this.chasis = chasis;
}

public void setMotor(String motor) {
    this.motor = motor;
}

public void setTonelaje(String tonelaje) {
    this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
}
```

Y finalmente el adaptador:

```
public class VehiculosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VehiculosAdapter.VehiculoHolder>{
 ArrayList<Vehiculos> list;
      ArrayList<Vehiculos> listOriginal;
      ArrayList<Vehiculo>listaCompleta;
      FirebaseAuth auth;
     DatabaseReference mDatabase;
     List<Vehiculos> items;
 public VehiculosAdapter(ArrayList<Vehiculos> list){
             this.list=list;
             listOriginal=new ArrayList<>();
              listaCompleta=new ArrayList<>();
              listOriginal.addAll(list);
 }
@NonNull
@Override
public VehiculoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.vehiculo_card,viewGroup,false);

    return new VehiculoHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VehiculoHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.modelo.setText(list.get(i).getModelo());
        holder.marca.setText(list.get(i).getMarca());
        holder.anio.setText(list.get(i).getAnio());
        holder.chasis.setText(list.get(i).getChasis());
        holder.tonelaje.setText(list.get(i).getTonelaje());
        holder.motor.setText(list.get(i).getMotor());
        holder.placa.setText(list.get(i).getPlaca());
        holder.itemView.setTag(list.get(i));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  final DialogPlus dialogPlus = 
                  DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.modelo.getContext())
                            .setContentHolder(new 
                   ViewHolder(R.layout.fragment_datos_vehiculos_actualizar_eliminar))
                        .setExpanded(true,1200)
                        .create();
     
                View view=dialogPlus.getHolderView();
                EditText anio= view.findViewById(R.id.Id_AnioVehiculo);
                EditText chasis= view.findViewById(R.id.ChasisVehiculo);
                EditText tonelaje= view.findViewById(R.id.TonelajeVehiculo);
                EditText motor= view.findViewById(R.id.id_MotorVehiculo);
                EditText modelo= view.findViewById(R.id.ModeloVehiculo);
                EditText marca=view.findViewById(R.id.id_ModeloVehiculo);
                EditText placa=view.findViewById(R.id.Id_NumeroPlacaCarro);

                Button btnUpdate=view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonActualizar);
                modelo.setText(holder.modelo.getText());
                marca.setText(holder.marca.getText());
                placa.setText(holder.placa.getText());
                anio.setText(holder.anio.getText());
                chasis.setText(holder.chasis.getText());
                tonelaje.setText(holder.tonelaje.getText());
                motor.setText(holder.motor.getText());
                dialogPlus.show();
                btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        String id=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("NumeroPlaca",placa.getText().toString());
                        map.put("ModeloVehiculo",marca.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Modelo",modelo.getText().toString());
                        map.put("AnioFabricacion",anio.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Motor",motor.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Chasis",chasis.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Tonelaje",tonelaje.getText().toString());
                                 
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(id)
                                .child("Vehiculo").updateChildren(map)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Toast.makeText(holder.anio.getContext(), "Se ha 
                                        actualizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                  }
                               });
                              }
                            });
                                });
                            }

                        @Override
                      public int getItemCount() {
                            return list.size();
                      }

                   public class VehiculoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                     public TextView anio;
                      public TextView categoria;
                     public TextView chasis;
                    public TextView colorPrimario;
                    public TextView colorSecundario;
                    public TextView modelo;
                    public TextView marca;
                    public TextView placa;
                    public ImageView imagen;
                    public TextView tipo;
                    public TextView tonelaje;
                    public TextView motor;
                     public TextView ModeloVehiculo,Id_NumeroPlacaCarro,id_ModeloVehiculo;

                       public VehiculoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                       anio=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.anio);
                    /* categoria=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_MotorVehiculo);*/
                       chasis=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chasis);
                      /*colorPrimario=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorPrimario);
                      colorSecundario=(TextView) 
                       itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorSecundario);*/
                       modelo=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelo);
                        marca=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marca);
                      placa=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placa);
                     /*tipo=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);*/
                     tonelaje=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tonelaje);
                      motor =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.motor);
                       }
                   }
                  public void filtrado(String idBuscador){
                   int longitud=idBuscador.length();
                       if(longitud==0){
                           list.clear();
                         list.addAll(listOriginal);
                      }else{
                     List<Vehiculos> collection =list.stream()
                        .filter(i- 
                       >i.getPlaca().toLowerCase().contains(idBuscador.toLowerCase()))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
                       list.clear();
                     list.addAll(collection);
                  }
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
```

Aqui esta el problema en la parte del Adapter:

```
 auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        String id=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        /*mDatabase= 
                         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(id);*/
                        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("NumeroPlaca",placa.getText().toString());
                        map.put("ModeloVehiculo",marca.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Modelo",modelo.getText().toString());
                        map.put("AnioFabricacion",anio.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Motor",motor.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Chasis",chasis.getText().toString());
                        map.put("Tonelaje",tonelaje.getText().toString());
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(id)
                                .child("Vehiculo").updateChildren(map)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Toast.makeText(holder.anio.getContext(), "Se ha 
                                     actualizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

Como puedo identificar de forma correcta el Id del vehiculo seleccionado en el Recyclerview , he intentado con child(getRef(i)) con la posicion (del holder) ,pero me sale un mensaje de error lo cual dice que no es compatible , a cambio si identifico mas o menos asi get(strinvalueof(i) me sale un nodo adicional y no el que esta seleccionado ( me agrega) , por eso digo , como puedo identificar el id del vehiculo seleccionado para poder actualizar un vehiculo de forma correcta.Si me pueden ayudar justo a tiempo a buena hora ya que necesito corregir urgentemente esa parte del código.Gracias.